# Flutter - Lines between containers

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a Flutter page but I have 2 lines that I don't know how to hide.

This is my piece of code:

```
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: PsColors.mainColor,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Utils.isLightMode(context)
                  ? const Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
                  : const Color(0xFF303030),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(50.0))),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: DropdownBaseControllerWidget(
              title: Utils.getString(context, 'MyDropDownField'),
```

This is the image:

[image]

How can I hide these lines?

Comment: try seting https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/elevation.html to 0

Answer (score -1):

You can remove these lines using `border`

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border.all(
    width: 0, 
    color: yourContainerColor, //the one you prefer
  ),
```